# How to display just "searched" data on the page in table?

Tags: php, database, laravel, search-form

I made search form and trying to retrieving data by searching. But before I begin to search data already retrieving on the page. Because I made controller that way already. When I delete that retrieving function, page running just white screen. So the problem is here, I want to see table and data retrieving after search not the before. But troubled about how to do that or doing it wrong.

Here is controller:

```
public function welcome()
{

    $estates = Estates::orderBy('price')->get();

    $data['estates'] = $estates;
    return view('welcome', $data);

}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    if (trim($q) !== ""){//here

        $estates = \DB::table('estates')->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->get();

        dd($estates);

        if(count($estates) > 0){
            return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
        }

    }

    $estates = array();//here
    return view("welcome", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");//here
}
```

And also my Route:

```
Route::get("/", "PagesController@welcome");

Route::post("/search", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```

Also when I try to search, page is coming not as table, but as like this.

```
Collection {#221 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
}
```

If you need to see my view page, I can add it too. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Remove `dd($estates);` to show the view

Comment: Thanks for that small touch fixed one problem. But still retrieving all data on the page, without a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
public function welcome()
    {

        $estates = array();//here

        $data['estates'] = $estates;
        return view('welcome', $data);

    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->q;
        if ($q !== null && trim($q) !== ""){//here

            $estates = \DB::table('estates')
                ->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->get();

            if(count($estates) > 0){
                return view("search", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
            }

        }

        $estates = array();//here
        return view("search", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");//here
    }
```